# Не получается найти кнопку лайка в Instagram при работе с Selenium на Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

Я пишу бота для инстаграмм используя библиотеку Selenium. Написав код, который будет переходить по ссылкам постов, бот должен нажать кнопку лайка используя xpath, который я ему указываю, однако когда я копирую xpath из кода страницы и указываю его в коде, при запуске оно выдаёт ошибку:
`Message: Unable to locate element`.
Сижу я на Windows 10, перепробовал уже Google Chrome и Mozilla Firefox, однако результат один и тот же.
Вот часть кода который не работает:
hrefs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

```
            posts_urls = []
            for item in hrefs:
                href = item.get_attribute("href")

                if "/p/" in href:
                    posts_urls.append(href)
            
            for url in posts_urls:
                driver.get(url)
                time.sleep(5)
                like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div")
                like_button.click()
                time.sleep(4)
                driver.quit()
```